# A better way to assign only if the right side is not null?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

In Kotlin, I want to do an assignment only if another variable is not null (otherwise, no op). I can think of two succinct ways:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var x: Int? = null
    var n = 0

    // ... do something ...

    x?.let { n = it }  // method 1
    n = x ?: n         // method 2
}
```

However, they don't feel succinct enough, given the frequency I have to do them. The first method seems an overkill. The second method is nagging in requiring an expression after `?:`.

I suspect there must be a better way, something like `n =? x`? Or `n = x?`? Is there?

Comment: There is no dedicated syntax for performing this operation in Kotlin.

Answer (score 1):

Try `infix` to  '*simulate custom inﬁx operations*'

```
// define this
infix fun <T > T.assignFromNotNull(right: T): T = right ?: this

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Demo using

// Now, Kotlin infix-style
fooA assignFromNotNull fooB
barA assignFromNotNull barB
bazA assignFromNotNull bazB

// Old code, Java if-style
if (fooB != null) {
    fooA = fooB;
}
if (barB != null) {
    barA = barB;
}
if (bazB != null) {
    bazA = bazB
}
```

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do with the infix function definition. But what are those 3 lines of Kotlin code? I obviously don't know about Kotlin's metadata well enough.

Comment: Demo code copied from my project. I will clean it to make answer clear.

Answer (score 0):

There's the following:

```
val x: Int? = null
val n: Int = x ?: return
```

This compiles perfectly fine, even though `n` may not be assigned. Even calls that use `n` after its 'assignment' are allowed, e.g. `println(n)`, because the compiler only knows that `n` is `Int` and that's OK. However, any lines following the assignment will never be called, because we `return` from the scope. Depending on what you want, that's a no-op. We can't continue because `n` couldn't be assigned, so just return.

Another option is `val n: Int = x!!` which will throw a `NullPointerException` if `x == null` that should be handled elsewhere. I don't recommend this practice, because Kotlin offers cleaner methods to handle nullability.

Comment: My real use case is this: I am writing a wrapper function (in Kotlin) on top of a Java library. If a parameter is not null, its value is assigned to a corresponding field in the underlying object. If it is null, then nothing is done, leaving the field with its default value. There are more than one field to set, so returning in the middle is not an option. Thanks for the investigation and the suggestion, though.

Comment: Then, I guess your original method 2 is the best: it's clear, short, simple and achieves what you want.